# I am not able to use relative path to import parent file for my unittest

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-unittest

If I try to use the following in my `test.py`

```
from ..main import *
```

to launch unittest in vs code I get the following error:

```
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

However, that works fine from the console if I pass along `-t` like

```
python3 -m unittest discover -v -t ".." -s "/yadayada/python/tests"
```

Here is my `settings.json`

```
"python.unitTest.unittestArgs": [
    "-v",
    "-s",
    "/yadayada/python/tests"
],
```

Also, unittest works in VS Code if I import `main` into `test.py` like:

```
import sys import os

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../main'))     
from main import *
```

I have attempted to pass along the `-t` parameter to VS Code but it does not seem to help.

Comment: What if you pass `-t` from the `settings.json` as an *absolute* path, not a *relative* one? Perhaps VS code is starting from a different working directory.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you for the suggestion. I tried using the absolute path numerous times chopping off the deepest directory each time but it did not work. However, I also then tried shortening the starting path (-s) and stumbled upon a value that works. Thanks for your help.
For others that see this I would try setting the "-s" absolute path all the way to your test case and then removing one directory at a time while ignoring vs code errors about it not finding tests as you save settings.json.